# Reading data file with unequal number of columns using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a .dat file with numbers. In the first row, this file has five columns, and in all subsequent rows, it has four columns. I want to be able to read this file using numpy. I encounter the following error when I try to read this file at present:

```
In [3]: F1 = np.loadtxt(‘file.dat')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-3-c0f31adaf29a> in <module>()
----> 1 F1 = np.loadtxt(‘file.dat')

/Users/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding)
   1090         # converting the data
   1091         X = None
-> 1092         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1093             if X is None:
   1094                 X = np.array(x, dtype)

/Users/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in read_data(chunk_size)
   1014                 line_num = i + skiprows + 1
   1015                 raise ValueError("Wrong number of columns at line %d"
-> 1016                                  % line_num)
   1017 
   1018             # Convert each value according to its column and store

ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2
```

How can I read all the rows of the file except the first row using python? 
I have attached an example file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1urv00_SdpbnIYPaXCROkg5DdgNbxlTTF/view?usp=sharing).

Additionally, the first column of this file (minus the first row) has n^2 number of rows (in the example I have n=3 and the entries of the column are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9). I want to read the first column (minus the first row) and save it as a text file where of shape (n,n) (i.e. the text file should have n rows and n columns). That is to say, I want the saved matrix to have the entries in the following order:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
4.0 5.0 6.0
7.0 8.0 9.0
```

I will be thankful to have help.

Comment: `genfromtxt` is a little better at this, but it still needs the right number of delimiters, which is a big problem with the default `white-space`.  `usecols` can be used to limit the load to the minimum number of columns.  You can also tell it to skip the bad rows.

Comment: You could read the file line by line, split it, and perform your own corrections in the cases where the lines are too short.

Comment: hpaulj: Can you please give an example? I am new to python and I could not implement your suggestion. I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some experiments to do: (not optimized)
1. Read in the lines of the file:

**edit: The 'file.dat' file has empty lines. The `if line.strip()...` clause is to deal with the empty lines.**

```
with open('file.dat', 'r') as fhand:
    file_lines = [line[:-1] for line in fhand if line.strip() != ''] # remove the last character '\n'. **Remove empty lines**.
```

If you don't like the first row, drop it.

```
file_lines.pop(0)
```

Now that the remaining lines have the same number of columns of numerical entries, you can split entries in each line, and do the type conversion:

```
mat_raw = [[float(term) for term in line.split()] for line in file_lines]
```

You then get a float matrix. For convenience in slicing, convert it into numpy array.

```
mat = numpy.array(mat_raw)
# then you can do whatever you like. eg: first column
first_col = mat[:, 0]
# reshape it to n by n matrix:
res = first_col.reshape((n, n))
...
```

Depending on the format of your file and your goal, you may optimise this code for your own use.

Comment: Thanks Zheng for the helpful answer. I still this small error when I try the technique that you suggested: `    first_col = mat[:, 0]
IndexError: too many indices for array`  Apparently the code doesn't like the line ` first_col = mat[:, 0] `. How can I get around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JiWonSong Hi. Did it complain when you type `mat = numpy.array(mat_raw)`? If this line executed, can you tell me the results of these two lines?
`mat.shape` and `mat.dtype`?

Comment: @JiWonSong Ah. I see the problem. Somehow, there are empty lines in the `file.dat` file. in defining `file_lines`, add an `if` clause will do. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. After the edit, the code works fine for me.